# Javascript: Protoypal Inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am working on prototypical inheritance to know about it, this below code I am working on it. on the last lines, there are two console, the problem is, in two, one is displaying the and the other one not. Is my understanding is wrong? please help me to improve.

```
function Gadget(name, color)
{
   this.name = name;
   this.color = color;
}

function Gadgetnew(names, colors)
{
   this.part = names;
   this.Jack = colors;
}

Gadget.prototype = new Gadgetnew();

var newtoy = new Gadgetnew("webcam", "black");

console.log(newtoy.name); //Not working
console.log(newtoy.part) //Working
```

Comment: Essentially you can remove everything to do with `Gadget` from this code, because you're not using it at all. Given that, why would you expect `name` to work?

Comment: You should check out this article on prototypal inheritance http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-prototype-in-plain-detailed-language/

Comment: I think this line: `Gadget.prototype = new Gadgetnew();` wants to be something like: `Gadgetnew.prototype = new Gadget();`

Answer (score 0):

This is because name is assign to `nothing`. That's why it is `undefined`. second `Gadgetnew` should `inherit`, `Gadget` properties. It should be like `Gadgetnew.prototype = new Gadget();` not `Gadget.prototype.constructor = Gadget;`, because in this case`you're not using it at all.`
Example

```
function Gadget(name, color)
{
   this.name = 'I am Gadget name';
   this.color = color;
}

function Gadgetnew(names, colors)
{
   this.part = names;
   this.Jack = colors;
}

Gadgetnew.prototype = new Gadget();

var newtoy = new Gadgetnew("webcam", "black");

console.log(newtoy.name); // I am Gadget name
console.log(newtoy.part); // webcam
```